# Display chrome notifications from extension automatically

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, notifications

I'm making a chrome extension which will remind me to drink water after a time interval automatically. Till now what I've coded it shows notification after a time period but only after i click on the extension. I want the notification to popup automatically without having to click on the notification.

This is the code Ive tried

```
 function show() {
    var interval = {
        type: "basic",
        iconUrl: "icon48.png",
        title: "Drink water",
        message: "Its time to hydrate yourself!"
    }
    chrome.notifications.create('drink', interval);
}
  setInterval(show, 2000);
```

Comment: It sounds like you're using a popup, which will only activate if you click on it. Use a [background script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) instead so that it maintains state after you change page or exit from the popup.

Comment: @RossJacobs thanks that helped a lot but can you tell me how to access dom elements in that background script? Like i want time to be given by user so how will i access it from html page?

Comment: The content script will send a message to the background script. The link I gave you references this internal messaging.